# One-Time Pad user input text using a generated random bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, key, one-time-pad

I have tried implementing a very simple OTP in python but for some reasons that I don't understand I am getting an error which says: "*ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (4 bytes)*". 
I am a newbie to python and OTP as well!

Here is the code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

user_input = input("Write here:")

secret_key = '1234567890'

cipher = AES.new(secret_key, AES.MODE_ECB)
encoded = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(user_input))

decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(encoded))
print(decoded.strip())
```

Comment: That isn't a one time pad...

Comment: What do you mean? Can you elaborate further how a one-time pad is according to you please?

Comment: Two programming issues: key size and padding. Then you have security issues like using ECB, not using HMAC and not using a KDF

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your question

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article for a one time pad?